# Error : My java class object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jms

I am trying to follow the prog. mentioned here https://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/simplest-sample-applications-using-websphere-mq-jms/ but retrieving the queue,host,port etc. details through log4j.properties file, Below are the entries in log4j.properties`

```
     log4j.appender.JMS = com.log4j.Log4j_HelloWorld
        log4j.appender.JMS.HostName=MQEEQS.ABC.COM
        log4j.appender.JMS.Port=1414
        log4j.appender.JMS.QueueManager=MQEEQS
        log4j.appender.JMS.Channel=CLIENT.TO.MQEEQS
        log4j.appender.JMS.QueueName=QA.M01.MR.NOTIFICATION.FEED.DEV
```

and getting these properties in my java class **Log4j_HelloWorld** using property.getProperty but while running it as java application i am getting the below error in console -

```
log4j:ERROR A "com.log4j.Log4j_HelloWorld" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a5d08] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "com.log4j.Log4j_HelloWorld" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a5d08].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "JMS".
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
\nFAILURE\n
```

Comment: Kindly help....

Answer (score 0):

is your com.log4j.Log4j_HelloWorld implements Appender interface

mostly,we derive from AppenderSkeleton